# If $A=\bigcup F_i$ is a filtered algebra, why is the multiplication on $\mathcal{G}(A)=\bigoplus (F_n/F_{n-1})$ well-defined?

Tags: abstract-algebra

> From the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filtered_algebra#Associated_graded_algebra), suppose $A=\bigcup F_i$ is a filtered algebra, and $\mathcal{G}(A)=\bigoplus_{n\geq 0}G_n$ the associated graded algebra, where $G_0=F_0$ and $G_n=F_n/F_{n-1}$. The multiplication is defined by 
>   $$(x+F_{n-1})(y+F_{m-1})=xy+F_{n+m-1}.
> $$ Why is this well-defined?

If $x,x'\in F_n$ and $y,y'\in F_m$, such that $x-x'\in F_{n-1}$ and $y-y'\in F_{m-1}$, then
$$
(x-x')(y-y')=xy-x'y-xy'+x'y'\in F_{n+m-2}
$$
and then $xy-x'y'=x'y+xy'-2x'y'+z$ for some $z\in F_{n+m-2}$. Presumably the RHS is in $F_{n+m-1}$ so that $xy+F_{n+m-1}=x'y'+F_{n+m-1}$. But $x'y,xy',x'y'\in F_{n+m}$, so it's not clear to me why that would be true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you have
$$x'y + xy' - 2x'y' = x' (y-y') + y' (x - x') \in F_{n} F_{m-1} + F_{m} F_{n-1} \subseteq F_{n+m-1} $$
using your assumptions on $y-y'$ and $x - x'$.